# Elastic Search : Aggregating documents based on patterns

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have four documents in my index. These are as follows.

Client(::ffff:10.0.0.6:27787) Connected

Client(::ffff:10.0.0.6:27805) Connected

Client(::ffff:10.0.0.6:27823) Connected

Client(::ffff:10.0.0.6:27875) Connected

=================

I hope to aggregate these as follows.

Client(::ffff:10.0.0.6:_____) Connected

There are many documents with different patterns in an index, not only the above document pattern, and I hope to get all patterns by aggregating all documents in an index.

How can I do it with ES? If ES does not directly support such aggregations, any idea to do this?

Regards, 
Kangmo

Answer (score 0):

you need to split the data you index into specific fields for, in order to reliable aggregate on your data.

So, you need to have a process, that splits the string `Client(::ffff:10.0.0.6:27787) Connected` into `::ffff:10.0.0.6` and puts that content into its own field.

One possible way to do this is to use the ingest node. The ingest node has a so-called [grok processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/grok-processor.html) to extract structured data from text.

With this you could extract the ip address and the index it into its own field (you could also use the `ip` data type, so you can do CIDR style range queries if needed) - and then you can aggregate easily on that data.

Hope this helps!

--Alex